# Mistake in code, Macro variable should return first value in list but it is returning last value

Tags: sas-macro

There is a mistake in my code. It should return first value in list but returning last value. My Code

```
%macro r(one, two);
%local cnt num;
%let cnt=0;
%let num=0;
%do %while(%scan(&one,%eval(&cnt+1),%str( )) ne %str( )); 
%let cnt = %eval(&cnt+1);
%if %upcase(%scan(&one,&cnt,%str( )))=%upcase(&two) %then
%let num=&cnt;
%end;
&num 
%mend r;

option mlogic symbolgen;
%put b is at position %r(a b c b, b);
```

Output should be 2 But I am getting output as 4. Can anyone help me figure out my mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `while` loop should terminate as soon as it finds a match. Currently it continues matching and therefore `num` will be updated twice for values 2 and 4 before ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a criteria to exit your `while` loop once you find a match.  Otherwise it keeps looking, which is not what you're aiming for.

```
%macro r(one, two);
%local cnt num;
%let cnt=0;
%let num=0;
%do %while(&num.=0 and (%scan(&one,%eval(&cnt+1),%str( )) ne %str( ))); 
  %let cnt = %eval(&cnt+1);
  %if %upcase(%scan(&one,&cnt,%str( )))=%upcase(&two) %then
    %let num=&cnt;
%end;
&num 
%mend r;

option mlogic symbolgen;
%put b is at position %r(a b c b, b);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!